# Gradle sync failed: Illegal char at index 2

Tags: android, gradle

Working on a project pulled from bitbucket. Whenever I'm trying to build the gradle, the following error shows.

```
Gradle sync failed: Illegal char  at index 2: C\:\\Program Files (x86)\\Android\\android-sdk\analytics.settings
```

This project is working absolutely fine in other member's computer who pulled from the same repository. (one of them is actually the one who uploaded everything in the first place, works obviously fine in his system).

Now I am not able to understand the error message at all. I don't know what illegal character it's mentioning of.

Thank you in advance!

**build.gradle(Project)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
   }
}

repositories {
jcenter()
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.vinaygaba:creditcardview:1.0.3'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Edit**

I tried deleting the project and tried checking out from version control again. But now it wont even open the project since gradle cant be built.

[image: checkout]
**I tried both the options but it always shows the following error**

[image: error]

**Edit 2**
Please note that my others projects are building fine. So the problem has to be with this particular project

Comment: Try to delete your **build** dir and rebuid your project.

Comment: can you post full logcat

Comment: @QianSijianhao didnt work

Comment: @VishalThakkar thats the only line it displays

Comment: Something wrong with your **analytics.setting**.Check the second char in this file.

Comment: @QianSijianhao I dont know where this file is. The error takes me to the build.gradle (project) file though. The code in that file is already displayed here.

Comment: @VishalThakkar please check the edit. I cant open the project anymore.

Comment: use default gradle wrapper

Comment: The dialog just shows where the file is:C:\\Program Files(x86)\Android\android-sdk\analytics.setting

Comment: @QianSijianhao the file doesnt exist in this address

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue and now its resolved.Check if you are using the latest sdk version or not and update it if not.After you update the sdk, also cross check if your system environment variables are located properly.Then restart the project.